# How to get Nuxt SSR routeRules wildcard working?

Tags: vuejs3, nuxt.js

I'm trying to set nuxt's routeRules to enable SSR on one specific route, which generates more routes on demand, the main route is /images, it will generate more routes with the id of the image the user wants to see, for example /images/<uuid>.

Here's the ssr nuxt config i'm currently using

```
ssr: true,
    routeRules: {
      '/login': { ssr: false },
      '/logout': { ssr: false },
      '/': { ssr: false },
      '/gallery': { ssr: false },
      '/intro': { ssr: false },
      '/dropout': { ssr: false },
      '/camera': { ssr: false },
    },
```

When I navigate to any /images/<uuid> it still prints that it is being rendered on client side, i'm using `process.server`, the only way I got it working was by putting an specific route on routeRules, for example: `'images/VALIDUUID': { ssr: true }`, when I did that it rendered this specific route on SSR, but i'd like the `images/**` wildcard to work, it doesn't seem to tho, already tried with `'images/*': { ssr: true }`, it didn't work neither, I have ran out of ideas.

Comment: I tried making a simpler test, adding a simple page to the routeRules section, it is an static page and I set ssr: true for it, and still the variable process.server is false.